# Struct is padded to 8 bytes when 6 bytes seem sufficient

Tags: c, gcc, struct, cpu-architecture, bit-fields

In the write-up The Lost Art of Structure Packing, the author introduces `struct foo6 (...)` in [chapter 6](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_bitfields) :

```
struct foo6 {
    short s;
    char c;
    int flip:1;
    int nybble:4;
    int septet:7;
};
```

They explain that the padding is done as followed :

```
struct foo6 {
    short s;       /* 2 bytes */
    char c;        /* 1 byte */
    int flip:1;    /* total 1 bit */
    int nybble:4;  /* total 5 bits */
    int pad1:3;    /* pad to an 8-bit boundary */
    int septet:7;  /* 7 bits */
    int pad2:25;   /* pad to 32 bits */
};
```

But I don't get why the last bit field is padded to 32 bits. Following the previous explanations, I would have guessed a padding to 16 bits, because the strictest alignment condition is 2 bytes, for the short element. By padding 9 bits to the septet, the struct can be properly aligned on even addresses.

I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that it is a 32 bits system (as in `sizeof int` == 4) but it is not consistent with the previous explanations.

I have compiled printed the `sizeof (struct foo6)` with -m32 and -m64, and the result is indeed 8, not 6. But I still don't understand why.

Comment: I think the standard leaves a lot of this to the implementation.  Traditionally, bit field packing was based on the size of the integer type.  So in this example, if `int` is at least 16 bits, then all 3 bit fields would be placed in a single `int`.  Forcing them to fit within a single byte would only have happened if the bit field type had been `char` instead of `int`.  I'm not sure how standard that strategy is today.

Comment: @bdmt, `struct` has its own implementation dependent minimum alignment too.  Perhaps it is 4?  Consider the indexing inefficiency of an array of `struct foo6` if the size was 6 and not 8.  If the size is 6, 8, ..., why do you care?

Comment: Using `short flip:1;` / `short nybble:4;` etc., GCC, clang for x86-64 SysV, and MSVC for Windows x64, all make the struct 6 bytes.  https://godbolt.org/z/dh86dnWMc  So indeed, it's expanding the bitfield member out to the width of a full `int` for some reason.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sTEa1zYYn adds a function that stores each bitfield member to a global, so we can see where they are.  GCC/clang start the `int` bitfields in the 3rd byte, and leave a gap between `nybble` and `septet` so `septet` starts in a new byte (and new dword of the whole struct). MSVC (Win x64) puts all three bitfields in the second dword of the struct, leaving a padding byte before `flip`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't think so, for instance a struct of 3 `short` will not be padded to 8 bytes. See also Peter answer with 6 bytes struct.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for the snippets. It indeed looks like the `int` bitfields will be padded to the size of an `int` in this case. If you remove the `septet` however, the `flip` and `nybble` will be packed in a single byte. Weird.

Comment: Good idea to look at stuff without `septet`.  Interestingly, `alignof(foo6)` is 4 even in that case, apparently inherited from the `int` base type for the bitfield.  https://godbolt.org/z/x8v98axE3  So *that's* where the padding is coming from.  Luis Colorado's answer suggested alignment as an explanation.  Its reasoning doesn't fit the facts (e.g. predicts padding in the wrong place, and appears to predict that it would still be an 8-byte struct without `septet`), but at least the emphasis on alignment was a useful thing to look at for the bitfield members.

Comment: I just noticed your question title.  It definitely can't be 3 bytes; even without any of the bitfield members, that's just normal padding for `alignof(short)`, otherwise every other element of an array would have a misaligned `short s` member.  The actual question is about a struct that's 8 bytes when 6 would be sufficient.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct foo6 {
    short s;
    char c;
    int flip:1;
    int nybble:4;
    int septet:7;
};

struct foo7 {
    short s;       /* 2 bytes */
    char c;        /* 1 byte */
    int flip:1;    /* total 1 bit */
    int nybble:4;  /* total 5 bits */
    int pad1:3;    /* pad to an 8-bit boundary */
    int septet:7;  /* 7 bits */
    int pad2:25;   /* pad to 32 bits */
};
```

> I have compiled printed the sizeof (struct foo6) with -m32 and -m64,
> and the result is indeed 8, not 6. But I still don't understand why.

First of all - it is hard to understand which struct as you use the same names to make it unclear. Assuming not packing

1. `foo6`

```
short      [][]
char       []
padding    []
bitfields  [][][]
padding    []
```

total 8 bytes

2. `foo7`

```
short      [][]
char       []
bitfields  []   <-- GCC will pack them into char 
bitfields  [][][][]
```

total 8 bytes

Comment: The name is the same because it is supposed to be the same struct, the author of the article added the bit fields to explictly illustrate the padding.

Comment: @bdmt but you ask the question and it is not clear which one.

Answer (score 0):

Structs always need to be padded to fill the worst case of alignment of any of the fields used in the structure. This is what enforces the padding at the end of the structure, and can make one to think that some bytes are wasted at the end.  The reason of this is alignment.

Imagine that a structure makes padding of fields to make one of the fields to be aligned to a 32bit boundary, and finally the `struct` itself requires 27 bytes.  If you are to use it in an array, and don't pad it with one extra byte, the first element of the array will be aligned, but the second will be put at an address that is congruent to 3 mod 4, and every  multiple of 4 bytes field will be missaligned one byte of the structure.  And for this reason the compiler will add an extra byte at the end of the structure for padding.

Once said this, the alignment of any composed data type, will be the same as the one used in the substructure member with the biggest aligment requirements.  In the structure fields, the padding is required to align *the next field* correctly, and at the end, the padding is required to make the full data type aligned with the next entry in an array of the data type you are defining.  In this way you can compute padding and alignment for any compound data type, to be able to join this new created data type with any other in a new data structure, or an array of this new data type.

To compute this, the compiler saves in its type table two sizes, the element size, and the type alignment.  These quantities don't have to be equal, for example on a 32 bit machine a `short` is 2 bytes width, and it will normally have a 2 byte address alignment requirement, but it is possible that it can be accessed in one bus access if positioned at an address that is congruent to 1 mod 4, because it will fit *inside* a full word, and so have no penalty to be read in a single bus access (while this complicates calculations a lot, i will not enter on this case which is sheldom used) So the algorithm normally requires to check the computed offset of a field, and on adding its size, how the alignment is to fit the next field, and add the needed padding bytes to enforce the alignment of the next field.  So in the first pass, we will start computing the sizes and alignment requirements of all the fields in the list of fields, grouping the bitfields into the base type chunks (so the `int` size will be needed to adapt the bitfields into separate padding groups) This way, we have:

- `char` fields: These have size 1 and no alignment (consider alignment 1, so they can be aligned at any address)
- `short` fields: These have size 2 and alignment to even addresses (2).
- `int` fields: We'll consider a 32bit machine so they have 4 size and 4 alignment.
- `long` fields: 8 size, and 4 alignment (in a 32 bit machine, 8 alignment in a 64bit)
- `float` fields: 4 size and 4 alignment
- `double` fields: 8 size and 4 alignment.

Now assume we try to pad the `struct foo1` data type:

1. We start at 0 size, 0 alignment.
2. associate the size and alignment corresponding to the field we are adding.
3. If the offset left for this field doesn't correspond to the alignment, add
   as many bytes as necessary to match the alignment.
4. compute the new size of the `struct` and updtate the alignment if the alignment of this field is larger than the previously calculated.
5. Repeat from 2 until all fields are considered.
6. pad the structure as necessary to make its size a multiple of the alignment (round up to the next multiple of the so computed alignment)  This requirement allows this data type to be piled up to make an array.

If we apply this to `struct foo1` it will result in:

```
struct foo6 {
    short s;      /* two bytes size, two bytes alignment */
    char c;       /* one byte size, one byte alignment */
    int flip:1;   /* next three fields fit in one 32bit int so
                   * 4 bytes size, 4 bytes alignment. */
    int nybble:4;
    int septet:7;
};
```

- s field will be at offset 0, and will set size to 2, alignment to 2
- c field will be at offset 2, and will set size to 3, alignment to 2
- flip, nybble and septet have an alignment requirement of 4, so as offset is 3, one extra byte of padding is needed to make offset a multiple of 4 this padding is added before this field.  offset is 4, alignment is 4.
- offset is 4 and alignment and it's a multiple of alignment, so no padding necessary at end, we are finished, final `struct foo1` size: 8, alignment: 4.

In the case of `struct foo2`:

```
struct foo6 {
    short s;       /* 2 bytes, alignment 2 */
    char c;        /* 1 byte, aligment 1 */
    int flip:1;    /* group 1: flip, nybble and septet */
    int nybble:4;  /* total 12 */
    int septet:7;  /* size 4, alignment 4 */
    int pad2:25;   /* size 4, alignment 4 */
};
```

- field `s`: offset 0, size 2, alignment 2, total size 2, total alignment 2.
- field `c`: offset 2, size 1, alignment 1, total size 3, total alignment 2.
- field group 1: offset 4 (to match alignment of this field, introducing a pad of 1 before it), size 4, aligment 4, total size 8, total alignment 4.
- field group 2: offset 12, alignment 4, no padding, total size 16, total alignment 4.
- as total size (16) is a multiple of alignment (4) no extra padding is needed at the end to make the data alignable with siblings in an array.

Comment: Alignment seems to be the key, but GCC for x86-64 SysV doesn't lay out the struct the way your analysis predicts. It puts the first 2 bitfield members in the 4th byte, right after `char c`, whether or not there's an `int septet:7` field.  https://godbolt.org/z/x8v98axE3 . And `alignof(foo1)` is 4 in that case, despite the fact the bitfield doesn't start on a 4-byte boundary.  Code that accesses the bitfield uses a byte load, not dword, so you'd expect to get similar alignment to another `char` member, but apparently `alignof(int)` applies even though the actual bitfield is much narrower.

Comment: Using `short flip:1` etc. does result in a total struct size of 6 bytes, with alignof = 2. The exact same layout within the struct.   The version of `foo6` with `int pad2:25;` (https://godbolt.org/z/GEYYf7q6E) has size 8, align 4 in x86-64 SysV.  In Windows x64, it has size 12, align 4.  So your detailed analysis is not how compilers / ABI rules actually work.  It's one way they might work, but they're not that keen on alignment of bitfields, so it's surprising they still inherit `alignof()` the base type of the bitfield when they're small.  (So maybe to keep the rules simpler?)

Comment: That's implementation dependant.  I've never looked at the algorithm used in GCC, just it's my idea in case I had to implement it.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And the argument your answer makes only applies to implementation choices other than GCC makes which is what the question asks about.  I think it is valid for the choice MSVC makes, since I think it does pad so the bitfield starts on a 4-byte boundary, even if `septet` is omitted, making size 8, align 4.  An explanation that might have been the reason, but isn't, doesn't seem like a good general answer.